# Download of QGIS Version 3.24 'Tisler' not available

Tags: qgis, installation, osx

I've tried to find the OS X installer for QGIS Version 3.24 'Tisler' but couldn't find it anywhere in the installer archive. Many other, much older versions but not 3.24

Can anybody tell me where to find it please?

Comment: Are you specifically after 3.24? The current releases are 3.26 and the long-term (LTS) 3.22.

Comment: Did you check https://download.qgis.org/downloads/macos/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download older QGIS point releases (pr) for MacOS from https://download.qgis.org/downloads/macos/pr

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here are the direct download links (2022-10-01):

- dmg: https://download.qgis.org/downloads/macos/pr/qgis_pr_final-3_24_0_20220223_132611.dmg
- md5: https://download.qgis.org/downloads/macos/pr/qgis_pr_final-3_24_0_20220223_132611.dmg.sha256sum